# JQuery object vs HTMLElementxxx Object

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('h1').click(function(){console.log("clicked");};
```

this does not:

```
var h1 = $('h1');
h1[0].click(function(){console.log("clicked");}
```

this works again:

```
var h1=$('h1');
var h2 = $(h1[0]).click(function() {console.log("clicked");}
```

Would anybody explain why?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers
Long

Answer (score 5):

`h1[0]` refers to the first element matched from your jQuery selector inside of an array. So, this is going to be a plain DOM element. As a result you must use that api. `onclick` would work there (if you assigned the function to it).

This would work:

```
var h1 = $('h1');
h1.click(function(){console.log("clicked");});
```

or this as well:

```
var h1 = $('h1');
h1[0].onclick = function(){console.log("clicked");};
```

The reason this one works (`var h2 = $(h1[0])`) is because you are taking the plain DOM element, and then wrapping it in a jQuery object, which allows access to the jQuery api.

It is for this situation that it is highly recommended from a readability standpoint that you name all of your jQuery object variables starting with a `$`. Thus,

```
var $h1 = $('h1');
$h1.click(function(){console.log("clicked");});
```

Comment: **+1** for your last recommendation, using `$` for naming jQuery object variables.